# PHP cannot POST with file_get_contents() content exceeding 1024 chars

Tags: php, limit, file-get-contents

I encountered a problem using `file_get_contents()`.

I `POST` form data to a remote script using `file_get_contents()` and that works fine for short forms (i.e. `$postdata < 1024`), but when the content of my form exceeds those `1024` chars (`$postdata > 1024`) then `file_get_contents()` has problems communicating with the remote script returning always an empty string (not false)

and there's nothing wrong with the remote script, for the tests I have even modified it to return just "OK", but as I said for `$postdata > 1024` - I get in return just an empty string (and the remote script isn't doing what it is supposed to do)

here is the code:

```
$postvals = array(
  'from' => 'Test <test@test.com>',
  'to' => 'test2@test.com,
  'subject' => 'Test',
  'body' => $mail_html_content
);

$postdata = http_build_query($postvals);

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => array(
      'Connection: close',
      'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length: '.strlen($postdata),
      'Custom-header: test'),
    'content' => $postdata,
    'timeout' => 40
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://test.com/script.php', false, $context, -1, 40000);
```

BTW my server `post_max_size` is set to `100M`

`phpinfo()` for the server doesn't report any `1024` or 1k values (besides `log_errors_max_len 1024`)

where could be the problem with this script?
(and I prefer not to use curl for that)

Comment: `post_max_size` on your server is irrelevant - look for other problem.

Comment: it is the same machine - I'm testing on different domains - so I know post_max_size is enough; unfortunately I have looked already for problems in all places that I can think of, and googled for similar problems too, but no luck :( so I decided to ask a question here as a last resort

Comment: Well, I believe the problem *might* be on the other side. Would you share some of the server side code then. A `var_dump($_POST)` could also help. And check the receiving side error logs.

Comment: For the testing the remote script does noting `<?PHP die("OK"); ?>`, logs show no errors, for `$postdata > 1024` I don't get any feedback from the remote script so `var_dump($_POST)` neither :( for `$postdata < 1024` I get my "OK"

Comment: Your web server limits the POST size, too. Have you checked the access.log and error.log of whatever httpd server you're using? Check the configuration and update that limit to a suitable value.

Comment: succesfull remote script response: `"POST /script.php HTTP/1.1" 200 203 "-" "-"`  / unsuccesful: `"POST /script.php HTTP/1.1" 200 84 "-" "PHP/5.3.28"`  / no errors in the error_log / post limit as I said earlier is 100M (for both domains)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your script on my server with a 50Mb file and it worked with a few hitches.

1. I've set post_max_size=200Mb
2. I've set memory_limit=-1 (I have plenty of it)
3. Keep in mind that you need the memory to open the file and next to copy and encode that string in http_build_query(). It took **almost 300Mb** of memory and I'd say you need at least double for a 100Mb file. Also, you need approximately the same amount on the other side that handles the post. Well, the other side for you is the same machine, so shares the same memory and what I am thinking here is that you're running out of memory.
4. Your `'to'` key is missing a trailing quote.

Again, the code generally works, so make sure you have enough RAM and if possible try on another server.

Comment: thanks for your time blue, I plan to use the script for sending post data of 1-10kb, this huge post_max_size limit is set by my hosting provider... in my desperation I gave `file_get_contents()` a rest and tried my luck with `fsockopen()` and it works fine now.. although I still don't know why `file_get_contents()` doesn't like data bigger than 1024 chars